# Express 4.17 req.body is empty

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, postman

I'm hoping you can help me out here because after trying over a dozen s/o solutions and reading the express docs several times, I'm stumped. I'm building a Node app that will (in the end) accept a POST from the front end app, persist it to Mongo then allow back end users to manipulate the data.  I am just getting going, trying to get the POST route working and have this so far:

app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AppData = require("./model/AppData");
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/lunch"
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

const router = require("./routes/index");
const PORT = 3005;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use("/", router);
app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({strict: false}));

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`The Backend Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

index.js (routes...plan on changing the name)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const appDataController = require('../controllers/appDataController');

router.post('/submit', appDataController.createAppData);

module.exports = router;
```

and appDataController.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AppData = mongoose.model('AppData');

exports.createAppData = (req, res) => {
    let reqData = req.body;
    console.log(reqData);
    res.send(reqData);
}
```

Simple enough, really, but when I grab Postman and set up a request using body/raw/json and send

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": "21"
}
```

I always see that body is undefined. From everything I've seen, I'm not doing anything wrong, but the result clearly indicates otherwise...What is it that I've missed?

Comment: `app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));` - But why?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please make sure to set it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because your using your express.json middleware after the routes, change this:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AppData = require("./model/AppData");
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/lunch"
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

const router = require("./routes/index");
const PORT = 3005;
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({strict: false}));
app.use("/", router); // this need to be here

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to MongoDB');
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`The Backend Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

first comes the middlewares and then the routes(depends on the middleware your using ofcurse).

Comment: Worked birlliantly! Thank you! I'll need to go through the docs with a finer toothed comb soon...right now I'm in "get it done" mode :)

Answer (score 0):

You should also include `urlencoded` option to get the body on `x-www-form-urlencoded` body for POST requests.

```js
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"}));
app.use(express.json({strict: false}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false})); // include this line
app.use("/", router);
```